# Average norm of a N-dimensional vector given by a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, normed-spaces, random, vectors

I'm interested in knowing what is the expected value of the norm of a vector obtained from a gaussian distribution in function of the number of dimensions $N$ and $\sigma$, i.e:

$$E[\|x\|_2],\quad x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma I_N)$$

I tried to search for this but didn't find anything. Can I get some help from you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above answer contains mistakes, as has been noted in the comments. I needed recently to derive this so the general result is:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[||x||_2^n\right] = 2^\frac{n-2}{2}\sigma^n N \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{N+n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{N+2}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: I don't have necessary knowledge to assert which of these solutions is the correct one. Perhaps someone with some reputation can confirm this is correct and the above solution is wrong?

Comment: @jmacedo Both mine and Liyuan's are correct, in fact there are equivalent as I mentioned in a comment below his answer, feel free to choose any of the two answers.

Answer (score 17):

This amounts to integration in spherical coordinates $(r=\|x\|)$: 
$$
E(\|x\|) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma)^N } \frac{N\pi^{N/2}}{\Gamma\big(\frac{N}{2}+1\big)}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/(2\sigma^2)} r^{N-1} \,dr 
\tag1$$

This is not so bad: substitute $t=r^2/(2\sigma^2)$, so that $dt = r/\sigma^2$. The resulting integral gives [Euler's gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma$. I'll skip the boring cancellations and get to the result: 
$$
E(\|x\|) = \frac{\sqrt{2}\, \Gamma\big(\frac{N+1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(\frac{N }{2}\big)}\,\sigma
$$
As stated in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0621), where you can also find the inequalities
$$
\frac{N}{\sqrt{N+1}}\le \sigma^{-1}E(\|x\|)\le \sqrt{N}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Times $\sigma$? I guess so, since for 1 dimension I got [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+abs%28x%29+*+exp%28-%28x-0%29%5E2%2F%282*%5Csigma%5E2%29%29%2F%28%5Csigma*sqrt%282*%5Cpi%29%29+%2C+x+from+-inf+to+%2Binf)

Comment: @joxnas Right, I internally normalized $\sigma=1$ and forgot to include it in the answer.

Comment: @Yes: I am confused regarding (1). In the $N=2$ case the Jacobian is 
$r(N−1)=r$.  Also, in the two dimensional case the corresponding integral would be $E[\|X\|]=...\int...r^2dr$ but you have $...\int..rdr. Please help meunderstand. –  zoli 21 hours ago

Answer (score 7):

When $\sigma=1$, this is the first moment of [Chi-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). Furthermore, \begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I)}\{ \|x\|_2^k \} = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)}\{ \|\sigma x\|_2^k \}= \sigma^k \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)}\{ \| x\|_2^k \}, 
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)}\{ \| x\|_2^k \}$ is the $k$th moment of Chi-distribution, which has value 
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)}\{ \|x\|_2^k \} = 2^{k/2} \frac{\Gamma((N+k)/2)}{\Gamma(N/2)}. 
\end{equation}

Two comments:
1. I think $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma I_N)$ should be replaced by $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I_N)$ in the original post. 
2. This result is different from that of Botev's. 
Let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: The two formulas are equivalent -> G(N/2)=G((N+2)/2)*2/N, but I did not see the simplification when I derived this.