# Expected norm of multivariate gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, normed-spaces, random

There's a derivation for a special case of standard normal in [Average norm of a N-dimensional vector given by a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827826/average-norm-of-a-n-dimensional-vector-given-by-a-normal-distribution)

Is there a nice expression for the case of arbitrary diagonal covariance matrix?

Comment: Squared norm yes, norm no.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409117) has a reference to it.

Comment: hm, I found the paper online [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704013), but don't see the formula there

Comment: The reference I meant was: "Multidimensional Gaussian Distributions" by Kenneth S. Miller (1964 edition, chapter 2, section 2)

Comment: I only got a copy of the book now, and was disappointed to find that where the author talks about "diagonal covariant matrix" (prior to Theorem 1 of Ch. 2 sec 2), he then proceeds to write a scalar multiple of identity. For general covariance there is some complicated symbolic expression with fractional derivatives in Theorem 7 of the same chapter; I don't know if it's of any practical use -- it's of the same kind as the last Theorem (page 909) of the Blumenson-Miller paper . Sorry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723181/distribution-of-squared-euclidean-norm-of-gaussian-vector for squared norm