# Magnitude of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

Let's say $X \sim \mathcal{N(0,\Sigma)}$ where $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Is there anything we can say about

$$\mathbb{E}_{x\sim X}\left[\sqrt{\sum_i^n x_i^2}\right]$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827826/average-norm-of-a-n-dimensional-vector-given-by-a-normal-distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Problem is they use a diagonal covariance matrix. I was hoping to have a more general solution.

Comment: Google something along the lines of 'expected norm of gaussian vector'.

Comment: See, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155829/euclidian-norm-of-gaussian-vectors

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague. A crude upper bound can be obtained with Jensen's inequality: 
$$E(\|X\|_2)\leq \sqrt{E(\|X\|_2^2)}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{ii}} = \sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(\Sigma)}$$